# Inferenecs from the given: x = nonhomogenous + homogenous solution solve Ax = b. (GStrang P161, Ex 3.4B.4)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given: All solutions to $\mathbf{Ax = b}$ have the form $\mathbf{x} = (1, 1, 0)^T + c(1, 0, 1)^T$.
>
> $\Large{\color{red}{1. [}}$ Then $A$ must have $n = 3$ columns. $\Large{\color{red}{]}}$  With $(1, 0, 1)$ in the $\ker A$,
> since $\mathbf{Ax = 0} \iff RREF(A)\mathbf{x = 0}$,
> column $1$ [of both $A$ and $RREF(A)]+$ column $3$ [of both $A$ and $RREF(A)$] $ = 0$.
> Column $2$ must NOT be a multiple of Column $1$, or [else] the nullspace would contain another special solution.
> $\Large{\color{red}{2. [}}$ So the rank of $A = 3 - 1 =2$. $\Large{\color{red}{]}}$
> $\Large{\color{red}{3. [}}$ Necessarily, A has $m \geq 2$ rows. $\Large{\color{red}{]}}$   The right side $b$ = column $1$ + column $2$.

Independence, basis, dimension, orthogonality, determinants succeed P161 in Strang's *Intro to Linear Algebra*, 4th ed, so will you please to exclude/pretermit these concepts.

$1.$ $\mathbf{x}$ is a $3 \times 1$ vector. By virtue of the accord of sizes in matrix multiplication, $\mathbf{x}$ is a $3 \times 1$ vector $ \Longrightarrow \mathbf{A}$ has $3$ columns. Are there other less pedestrian ways to deduce this?

$2.$ I register $(1, 1, 0)^T$ as $1$ solution to the nonhomogenous linear system. Then how to proceed?

$3.$ Since $\mathbf{A \neq 0}$, I thought $m \geq 1$ row(s). How and why $m \geq 2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a (non-rigorous) way to look at it. Try working backwards. We are given that:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 = 1+c \\
x_2 = 1 \\
x_3 = c
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
x_1 = 1+x_3 \\
x_2 = 1 \\
x_3 \text{ is free}
\end{cases}
$$
Since $x_1,x_2$ are basic variables and $x_3$ is a free variable, the smallest possible row-reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix $[A|b]$ would have the form:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

We know that $m \geq 2$ because the number of rows in the matrix must be greater than or equal to the number of pivots in the matrix (that is, the rank of the matrix). To make the inequality strictly greater, we can add any number of zero rows to the bottom of the augmented matrix.